# How to catch mouse event and get clicked element with Windows Automation API?

Tags: c++, windows, ui-automation

I would like to get any element that was clicked by mouse pointer. That could be a button or a window or a menu item, anything. I only need bounding box size information. It seems that Windows Automation API is able to get UI elements as a tree and one can get information on an element through it (In specs, there are properties about the bounding box). However, I have no clue how to get that tree and retrieve the element that was clicked by user. There are several pages on the web that explains the main philosophy but no useful samples of implementation with them.

How can I catch event with Automation API and get the triggered element?

EDIT:

I've found **how to retrieve target info**:

```
<uiautomation.h>
<ole2.h>

HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
if (FAILED(hr))
    ...

IUIAutomation *_automation;
hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(CUIAutomation), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&_automation));
if (FAILED(hr))
    ...

POINT p;
GetCursorPos(&p);
IUIAutomationElement *_element;
hr = _automation->ElementFromPoint(p, &_element);
if (FAILED(hr))
    ...

// By example, get position and size information.
VARIANT _target_info;
hr = _element->GetCurrentPropertyValue(UIA_BoundingRectanglePropertyId, &_target_info);
if (FAILED(hr))
    ...

double *_data;
SafeArrayAccessData(_target_info.parray, (void**)&_data);
double posx = data[0];
double posy = data[1];
double width = data[2];
double height = data[3];
```

Comment: im pretty sure my post helped you get to the solution, please mark it as answer, i could have only named the functions you needed but i posted  code that is working for me

Comment: Sorry, even if it is probably correct in C#, it is not the same thing in C++. Because the Win API access to the UI data in a pretty obscure way (SafeArrayAccessData and so on), that's what I looked for help at SOF. Thank you though, I let your answer her because it can help C# developers but I can't mark as answer since it won't help Windows C++ developers.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way i can know that is that element is invokable(buttons are invokable) ,Expandable(Combo boxes are expandable) , or selectable ??